# How to add DesiredCapabilities to GeckoDriver in Selenium-Java 3.11

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, mutablecapabilities

Am trying to use `GeckoDriver` for firefox in `selenium-java 3.11`. The firefox version is `59`. Things are working fine and am able to invoke the firefox driver. The only challenge is I need to add `DesiredCapabilities` to my firefox instance.

The old method `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);` in latest selenium version seems to be deprecated and am not able to figure out the new way to specify the capabilities.

Here is the code:

```
public static WebDriver createDriver(String userAgentKey, String PROXY) {


     File modifyHeaders = null;
     try {
     modifyHeaders =
     ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi");  //am adding the extension using DesiredCapabilities
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

     e1.printStackTrace();
     }

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY).setFtpProxy(PROXY).setSslProxy(PROXY);



    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", true);
    profile.setPreference("brower.link.open_newwindow", 1);


    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.active", true);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", true);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "Proxy-Authorization");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "Basic dnNodWtsYUBleHBlZGlhLmNvbTpxZWxsYWZraw==");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", true);

    profile.addExtension(modifyHeaders);

    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/vshukla/Music/geckodriver");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);  //this is deprecated


    return driver;
```

How can I add the extension to instance using DesiredCapabilities? What are other options to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox options :

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

Comment: Though this gives the right way to set capabilities, still I don't see the extension added to my instance.

Comment: are you talking about profile.addExtension(modifyHeaders); ?

Comment: you can use this method also for that purpose : options.setProfile(profile);

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *FirefoxOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *FirefoxOptions* object as follows :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/vshukla/Music/geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(cap);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
```

PS : As a reference you can have a look at the discussions in [**`mutablecapabilities`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutablecapabilities) tag